# Font Awesome - icon set from server

Tags: android, font-awesome

I am getting code from server for set icon in application, code is `&#xf003;` 
but not getting icon in textview display code only. 
i will try to set like - `[&#xf003;]` , 0xf003, but not getting icon.

```
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    String s = obj.msg_icon;
    holder.txticonnotify.setText(s);
    holder.txticonnotify.setTypeface(font);
```

Output

```
&#xf003;
```

if set same code from string.xml it will work fine.

**How to get Icon**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should convert it:

```
Html.fromHtml(s).toString();
```

*note that createFromAsset is an expensive call, so don't use it in a cycle.

Comment: then where i will create asset for adapter icon "holder.txticonnotify.setText(s);" @Ashkan

Comment: You can create your typeface in adapter constructor.